# Can't resolve declaration with ts-loader and webpack

Tags: typescript, webpack

## Context

- "ts-loader": "^6.2.1",
- "typescript": "^3.7.2",
- "webpack": "^4.41.2",
- "webpack-cli": "^3.3.9",
- "webpack-dev-middleware": "^3.7.2",
- "webpack-dev-server": "^3.9.0"

## Issue

In order to import `.html` file, i am using the following declaration in a file `html-loader.ts` :

```js
declare module "html-loader!*" {
    const content: string;
    export default content;
}
```

This declaration is used in an other file as follow :

```js
import htmlcode from 'html-loader!./template.html';

...
```

The project is built using **`webpack`** and  **`ts-loader`**.

Here is the content of `tsconfig.json` used by `ts-loader`.

```js
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "dist",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": [ "es2015", "dom" ],
    "sourceMap": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "removeComments": true,
    "noEmitOnError": true,
    "declaration": true
  }
}
```

Here is the `webpack.config.js` :

```js
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    'lib': './src/index.ts',
  },
  devtool: 'source-map',
  mode: 'development',
  output: {
    filename: '[name].bundle.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    library: '[name]',
    libraryTarget: 'umd',
    umdNamedDefine: true,
  },
  module: {
      rules: [
        {
            test: /\.ts$/,
            use: 'ts-loader',
            exclude: /node_modules/,
          },
      ]
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: [ '.ts', '.js' ],
  },
};
```

The bundles are built but the built command `webpack` exit with error code `130` and the following message :

> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'html-loader' in '/path/to/file_that_use_declaration'

Any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

Using `raw-loader` webpack plugin did the trick.

First, install using `npm install raw-loader --save-dev`.

Here is the `webpack.config.js` :

```js
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    'lib': './src/index.ts',
  },
  devtool: 'source-map',
  mode: 'development',
  output: {
    filename: '[name].bundle.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    library: '[name]',
    libraryTarget: 'umd',
    umdNamedDefine: true,
  },
  module: {
      rules: [
        {
            test: /\.ts$/,
            use: 'ts-loader',
            exclude: /node_modules/,
        },
        {
            test: /\.html$/,
            use: 'raw-loader',
        }
      ]
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: [ '.ts', '.js' ],
  },
};
```

Here is the `html-loader.ts` containing the declaration :

```js
declare module '*.html' {
  const content: any;
  export default content;
}
```

The file is imported as following with `import HTMLVariable from './template.html';`.